# jQuery AutoComplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp, autocomplete

I want to build a jquery Auto Complete input field for the city the user stays in. When the user starts typing in the words i wanna display a list of 5 cities with the closest associations in this format [City, Country]

i have three tables

1. Country (id, country_name)
2. Region (id, region_name, country_id)
3. City (id, city_name, region_id, country_id)

when a user selects a city i want to capture the id of the City to insert it into the database.

How should i do this with Autocomplete ?

Should i set a hidden field with the id of the city or pass the name of the City and then check whats its id doing a select ? Problem here is there are cities across the globe with the same name and it will get diff to identify it.

JS code

```
$("#UserCity").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/baku/users/location/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                data: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                /// Need to modify this part
                response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

Example JSON String i get from Ajax

```
[{"name":"Banaras, Uttar Pradesh, India","city_id":"1927","region_id":"2193","country_id":"113"},{"name":"Banda, Uttar Pradesh, India","city_id":"1938","region_id":"2193","country_id":"113"},{"name":"Bangalore, Karnataka, India","city_id":"1949","region_id":"2185","country_id":"113"},{"name":"Banganapalle, Andhra Pradesh, India","city_id":"1950","region_id":"2169","country_id":"113"},{"name":"Banswara, Rajasthan, India","city_id":"1983","region_id":"2190","country_id":"113"},{"name":"Banur, Punjab, India","city_id":"1987","region_id":"2189","country_id":"113"}]
```

I wanna Display name as the list and take City_id as the passable parameter via the Form so that i dont need to again do a database query.

the Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banaras, Uttar Pradesh, India
            [city_id] => 1927
            [region_id] => 2193
            [country_id] => 113
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banda, Uttar Pradesh, India
            [city_id] => 1938
            [region_id] => 2193
            [country_id] => 113
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bangalore, Karnataka, India
            [city_id] => 1949
            [region_id] => 2185
            [country_id] => 113
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banganapalle, Andhra Pradesh, India
            [city_id] => 1950
            [region_id] => 2169
            [country_id] => 113
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banswara, Rajasthan, India
            [city_id] => 1983
            [region_id] => 2190
            [country_id] => 113
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Banur, Punjab, India
            [city_id] => 1987
            [region_id] => 2189
            [country_id] => 113
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi.. which plugin you are use for auto complete . In UI Auto complete plugin it will also send you the id of the specific city ... http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/default.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
<input type="hidden" name="city_id" id="city_id" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('input.city').autocomplete('/ajax/autocomplete-city.php').result(function(e, data){
    $('city_id'.val(data[1]);
});
```

PHP:

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);

$rs = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        CONCAT_WS(', ', city.city_name, region.region_name, country.country_name)
    ,   city.id
    FROM
        city
    INNER JOIN
        region ON region.id = city.region_id
    INNER JOIN
        country ON country.id = city.country_id
    WHERE
        city.city_name LIKE '$query%'
    LIMIT 10
");

while ($r = mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
    echo implode("|", $r);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks Creadiff for the answer. i am confused with the string i am generating. i have added it to the question. My url will look something like this site.com/location/{what ever is typed} and i get back the Json string as i have posted.

Comment: The URL automatically sent by the Autocomplete plugin looks like this: **location/given/in/parameter?q=field+value**. The reponse consists of lines representing pipe-separated values (one line per result). See: http://dyve.net/jquery/autocomplete.txt

Comment: I am using the jQuery UI Autocomplete module. i am able to get back the JSON String as i have shown in the question. not able to handle it in JS code. Getting this Error: a is undefined. i am trying to modify an example give with ur code. will update the JS code into the question

Answer (score 1):

When faced with the possibility of 2 instances having the same name, I always add one more unique thing, to differentiate between them ( but this is only so that the users can make the right choice ). Normally, your cities should have different IDs ( they should be unique ).

Comment: when i display the content.. i will show [City, Region, COuntry] so that wont be a problem. i want to just get the content from the form to save it in the database